# Why are my network players only able to shoot horizontally in my first person shooter?

Tags: unity, c#, networking

I am quite new to the Unity community, but I can code in C#. I am testing Unity networking using a standard FPS. I am stuck while testing out multiplayer shooting, not using raycasts. The host can shoot wherever he wants, but other players can only shoot along the Y axis (left and right).

[Video describing my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Is7pX-rFkE&feature=youtu.be)

The way I handle rotations, the body only rotates left and right, and then I rotate the camera up and down; I don't want the body to rotate in that direction. I instantiate a bullet in front of my mesh and add velocity to its rigid body in the direction the camera is facing.

Why are my players only shooting in left or right direction?

---

**Here's my code for shooting:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Shoot : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float bulletSpeed = 30f;
    public float bulletDecay = 1f;
    public float bulletY = 0;
    public Camera cam;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            CmdFire();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdFire()
    {
        var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab,
        new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x, cam.transform.position.y + bulletY, 
            cam.transform.position.z) + cam.transform.forward, Quaternion.identity);

        // local
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = cam.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
        // net
        NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);

        Destroy(bullet, bulletDecay);
    }
}
```

**Here's the movement script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerMove : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam; // This object has been set via the inspector
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject mesh;
    public float spawnX = 0, spawnY = 0;
    public float bulletSpeed = 30f;
    public float bulletDecay = 1f;
    public float bulletY = 0;
    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;
    public float jumpForce = 1;
    public float rotateSpeed = 1.5f;
    public Vector3 v3Rotate;
    public float rotaceMin = -90, rotaceMax = 90;

    float distToGround;
    bool canJump = true;

    void Start()
    {
        // localplayer start
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            distToGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
            cam.transform.localEulerAngles = v3Rotate;
            return;
        }

        // turn off multiplayer cam and AuLi
        cam.enabled = false;
        cam.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        this.name = "Player";
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }

        // get axis
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // rotate left right
        var rotateLR = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;

        // rotate up down
        v3Rotate.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed;

        //rotate calculate limit up down
        v3Rotate.x = Mathf.Clamp(v3Rotate.x, rotaceMin, rotaceMax);
        cam.transform.localEulerAngles = v3Rotate;

        // move
        var inputModifyFactor = (x != 0.0f && z != 0.0f)? .7071f : 1.0f;
        x *= inputModifyFactor;
        z *= inputModifyFactor;
        transform.Translate(x*moveSpeed,0,z*moveSpeed);

        // calculate rotation left right
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, rotateLR, 0));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            //if(IsGrounded())
            if (canJump)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
                    .AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                canJump = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // make sure he is grounded
                if (IsGrounded())
                {
                    canJump = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
        }
    }

    public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        // turn off local mesh of player
        this.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }    

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1f);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        canJump = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with some way to see the issue happening if possible. In your case a short video or gif would be perfect, or, if you're comfortable with it, even an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: No problem I will do it now! Just a sec

Comment: Done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Is7pX-rFkE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I've removed your request for users to not edit your question. Editing questions to improve them is a core part of this site, and the original phrasing had some clarity issues. Occasionally we'll get an incorrect edit, but these can be rolled back and improved as they're found, and are not a cause for forbidding all edits.

Comment: Thank you very much but I think your edit from axis Y to horizontal plane is quite useless and less accurate at the moment. Becouse of your edits I almost forgot what i asked for. Please rather contribute to the answer then caring about the question. I am rollbacking this

Comment: Unfortunately your use of terminology in the current phrasing is unconventional, and likely to confuse users trying to answer your question. For instance "Why are my players only shooting along the Y axis?" - shooting along the Y axis in Unity means shooting directly up or down. This is in fact the *opposite* of the problem demonstrated in your video, where players can't shoot upward or downward, only outward toward the horizon. Leaving it this way, you might get answers to a different problem than the one you actually need to solve, or confuse users to the point that they don't answer at all.

Comment: Nope the axis is right. The problematic axis is the X rotation of the camera. And the name of my question was edited few hours ago by someone else... I will edit that for your satisfaction but please someone already help me please.

Comment: *Rotation around* the Y axis is not the same as *shooting along* the Y axis. Please trust me on this - take a look at my rep count and past posts if you have any doubts that I might have expertise that could be useful to you here. Going by your use of "rollbacking" as opposed to "rolling back," I'm guessing English may not be your first language. Putting your pride aside and letting other users who are native or proficient speakers help you phrase a clear question is an important step toward getting good answers.

Comment: Can we please answer here only if we can get closer towards the solution? I dont see the meaning of this conversation so far.

Comment: The meaning is trying to help you get better answers and helping you understand the terminology, Both of which will most likely result in you arriving at a solution much faster.

Comment: Day 4 and still no idea why is that happening :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after few days I was thinking maybe I did nothing wrong so I started looking into other posibilities than "mistake in the code". It felt like the player shoot script doesnt know about that camera rotation. So I tried to add **NetworkTransformChild** to a **Player prefab** and targeted the camera of the prefab and **it worked**...

I am not sure if it is not too much of an overkill trying to send so many transform data just for one prefab but I guess we will see later. If anyone see any problem with this solution like network overflow or something please let me know!

I will play with it now and see if I can for example send only X axis rotation.

[image: NetworkTransforChild solution]

***Thank you all for so much help and good edits on my question.***